# how to hide folders/paths in URL and just keep domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, .htaccess

I'm trying to host a wiki-style site on a private tumblr so that I can host my content for free while still having controlled access.

I don't have knowledge past HTML/CSS, plus I'm limited to following tumblr conventions so I can't just rearrange my directory to create cleaner looking paths. Since SEO isn't important to me and it'll mostly just be me using the site, I was wondering if it was possible to hide paths and only leave the main part of the URL.

For example, regardless of what page I navigate to within my subdomain:

```
personalwiki.tumblr.com/tagged/main/chrono
personalwiki.tumblr.com/timeline
personalwiki.tumblr.com/tagged/wikiEvent
```

They would all show up in the address bar as:

```
personalwiki.tumblr.com
```

I've seen similar questions and various solutions using htaccess, jQuery, and others, but since I'm not familiar with the languages, I'm not sure which is the easiest solution to use or if they're applicable to what I'm trying to achieve.

Thanks for any help and insight!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use domain masking for this, although not sure if this is an option in your case.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_masking

Try adding this javascript code to each of your tumblr pages:

```
window.history.replaceState('', '', '/');
```

This "should" navigate to the correct page, but change your URL to "http://personalwiki.tumblr.com"

Comment: If I'm understanding it correctly, URL rewriting would probably be the easiest method of domain masking to use. Is it possible to place a rewriting command into html using a script element or do you have to use one of listed frameworks as a host?

Comment: This is typically done on the server side, however I think you can do it with HTML5 on the client side now. http://spoiledmilk.com/blog/html5-changing-the-browser-url-without-refreshing-page/

Comment: Hmm. I read through this a few times and am not completely sure how this works since I'm not familiar with javascript. To me it looks like you can get the page to navigate to a new one without having it reload, but it would change the URL to that of the new page. So going from `example.com` to `example.com/about` without reloading. I'm not sure how to modify that so you can change the page without changing the url, meaning navigating to `example.com/about` but remaining at `example.com`

Comment: You can try to add this javascript code to each of your tumblr pages: `window.history.replaceState('', '', '/');`. This "should" navigate to the correct page, but change your URL to "http://personalwiki.tumblr.com". You may need to create a state object for the first parameter, but you would have to test and play around with it. More info on the `replaceState()` function here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState()_method

Comment: That code as is accomplishes what I'm looking for! Thanks for all of the help